# HTML Tables that disallow add / remove but allow update and save the final table into a array for later saving?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, html-table

Is there a JQuery Plugin or code that can perform the following on a HTML table?

- It disallow add / remove rows via some option
- It allow update only via some option
- It save the final table (after modification by the user) into a array
- There is a button that when click, it display the array (that will reflect any changes by the user)

I have tried using the Datatable as mention in [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/HTMLSource), but I keep getting the "Cell cannot be updated" message. Thus, would like to know if there are any more simpler solution available.

Answer (score 0):

you ca try this, people have a good feedback of.

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and for me it turn out to be that i wasn't passing the id of the row i was trying to edit

```
            <tr id="@item.ID">
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Address</td>
                <td>@item.Town</td>
            </tr>
```

Notice the id is set in the "tr" element